# Movie playing on iPad simulator but not on actual iPad

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been learning Swift slowly in my spare time, and still have a long way to go. I got tasked with putting together a simple demo of an interactive iPad book. Just a few pages of pictures and text, with a couple of Quicktime movies that launch when a button is pressed. As simple as it is, I'm still a bit above my head here, but I do like learning with these challenges.

I've cobbled it together so far using demos and bits of code I've found online (again, this is only for a demo to show how the idea can be used, and as a learning exercise; it's not anything that will be launched publicly in this form). I've got it so you can swipe between pages like turning the pages of a book, and, on the simulator, I've got it so that the movies open up when the button is pressed.

However, when sent to my actual iPad, the movie does not play. I get the blank Quicktime screen with a crossed out play button.

In my code, the URL to the movie file is the path to the movie on my harddrive. This is how it was shown in the demo I used to figure out how to do this, and I was assuming that would get fixed when xcode compiled the app, and it would show up locally to the app. Maybe I was wrong on this?

Here is the skeleton of the project. The code that plays the movie file is in jockeyproject/Swipe Navigation Xcode 7/ViewController0.swift.

Is my problem with that URL, or is there another issue at play here? How do I fix it?

https://github.com/fewdiodave/jockeyproject.git

Answer (score 0):

To package the file within your app, you have to drag the desired file into your Xcode project, and access it through the current `NSBundle`.

Accessing the bundle contents is described in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html) Apple document.

In Swift you would access the bundle resource like this

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video", ofType: "mp4")
```

Comment: Due to iOS sandboxed nature, you can't just put in a path, you have to get the path to your current sandbox (the `NSBundle`), and than relative to this path you can reference your video.

Comment: Oh man, I may be a bit over my head here. I thought this part would be a bit more straightforward. 

Okay, I basically understand the concept behind what you (and the linked document) are saying. The files were dragged to the project, and I need to programmatically access the url to it using the NSBundle. 

As far as I can figure, in Objective-C, that would be (I think):

NSString myVideoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myvideofile" ofType:@"mp4"];

Is that basically correct? So I need to figure out how to accomplish the same thing in Swift?

Comment: @DavidSchneider Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Leandros, that's very helpful! One more question, if you would be so kind. 

Here is where I'm at now:

`let pathToVideoFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1982BelmontStakes", ofType: "mp4")`

With 1982BelmontStakes.mp4 being the movie file that has been added to my xcode project.

Then calling it with: 

`override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "pathToVideoFile")
        playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
        
        playerViewController.player = playerView
        
    }`

What's my mistake?

Comment: Oh, I thought I caught my own mistake that it should be:

 `let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(pathToVideoFile)")`

But still not working.

Comment: I figure it out! Thanks again for the help and pointing me in the right direction. 

`let pathToVideoFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1982BelmontStakes", ofType: "mp4") as String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
   
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathToVideoFile!)
        playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
        playerViewController.player = playerView
    }`